# How to sort DynamoDB table by a single column?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

I'd like to list records from my DDB table ordered by creation date.
My table has an attribute `DateCreated`.

All examples I can find describe ordering within some partition.
But I want global ordering.
Am I supposed to create an artificial attribute which will have the same value across all records, just to use it as a partition key? E.g. add new attribute `GlobalPartition` with value `1` to every record in the table, and create a GSI with partition key `GlobalPartition` and sort key `DateCreated`. Isn't there a better way?

Thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you noticed, DynamoDB indeed does not have an option to sort items "globally". In other words, there is no way to `Scan` the database in sorted partition-key order. You can only sort items inside one partition, sorted by the "sort key".

When you have a small amount of data, you can indeed do what you said: Have a single partition with everything in this partition. However it's not clear how practical this approach becomes as your single partition grows - to gigabytes or terabytes, and how well DynamoDB can load-balance when you have just a single partition (I never saw any DynamoDB documentation which answer this question).

So another option is not to have a single partition but rather have a number of them. For example, consider that you want to sort items by date. Now insead of having a single partition, have a partition **per month**, i.e., the partition key is the month number. Now, if you want to sort everything within a month, you can do it directly, but if you want to get a sorted list of a full year, you need to `Query` twelve partitions, in order, getting a sorted list in each one and combining it to a sorted list for the full year. So-called *time-series* databases are often modeled this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort any data in DynamoDB you need to add Sort Key index on that attribute. If value is not in attribute which maps to tables' sort key, or table does not have sort key, then you need to create GSI and put GSI's sort key on that attribute. You can use LSI too. Any attribute, which maps to "Sort Key" of any index. Table, LSI, GSI.

Check for more details "ScanIndexForward" param of the query request.

> If ScanIndexForward is true, DynamoDB returns the results in the order in which they are stored (by sort key value). This is the default behavior. If ScanIndexForward is false, DynamoDB reads the results in reverse order by sort key value, and then returns the results to the client.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#API_Query_RequestSyntax

UI has checkbox too for this:

[image]

"Global sort" is not possible, while "global" would mean scan operation and it just runs through all rows in database and filters by filters, yet it does not have sorting option. On query on attribute mapped to sort key has ScanIndexForward option to change sort direction.

Comment: `Query` requires a particular partition key and returns only results with that key, sorted by the sort key.  OP wants *global* sort.

Comment: global sort is not possible, while "global" would mean scan operation and it just runs through all rows in database and filters by filters, yet it does not have sorting option. Adding this to main answer for clearance